# What is the maximum current limit of this motor?

Tags: dc, dc-motor

I am confused about the maximum current limit of this DC Motor.
Rated Power is given as 220W and Rate voltage is given as 24VDC. According to this maximum current should be 9.166A. But 2.5Amax is also mentioned on the name plate. So what should I consider as the maximum current limit so as to design the protection circuit for this motor?
[image: Motor Nameplate]

Comment: Please provide a link to the motor's datasheet.

Comment: Is it a stepper motor?

Comment: Does it have a brake? Some data could be related to the brake.

Comment: Remember to take the stall current into account aswell

Comment: @Andyaka I DON'T HAVE IT

Comment: @BrianDrummond NO, IT IS GEARED DC MOTOR

Comment: @MarkoBuršič YES, IT HAS BOTH MECHANICAL AND ELECTROMAGNETIC BRAKE

Comment: Why are you shouting at everyone?

Answer (score 1):

> Rated Power is given as 220W and Rate voltage is given as 24VDC. According to this maximum current should be 9.166A.

No, a **rated** unit \$ \neq \$ a **maximum** unit.

So, if the **rated** power is 220W and the **rated** voltage is 24Vdc, then the **rated** current should be 9.17A.

> But 2.5Amax is also mentioned on the name plate.

By definition the rated current \$ \leq \$ maximum allowed current.

**So, the shown specs are weird.**

Looking up a few other motors from [MOTION TECH MOTORS](http://www.motiontech.com.tw/eng/index3.asp) show the same remarkable data:

- [EC82M245330ALGB0](http://www.motiontech.com.tw/eng/inquire_View.asp?nid=49) MOTOR: 24Vdc 4.5A(max) OUTPUT: 300W RATIO 1:25
- [EC82L244840ALGBL](http://www.motiontech.com.tw/eng/inquire_View.asp?nid=38) MOTOR: 24Vdc 4.5A(max) OUTPUT: 400W RATIO 1:32
- [EC82M244632ALGBL0C](http://www.motiontech.com.tw/eng/inquire_View.asp?nid=36) MOTOR: 24Vdc 3.0A(max) OUTPUT: 320W RATIO 1:32
- [EC63L244727ARGBL](http://www.motiontech.com.tw/eng/inquire_View.asp?nid=42) MOTOR: 24Vdc 3.0A(max) OUTPUT: 270W RATIO 1:25

For all these motors, the output power is more than the (electrical) input power, which is, of course, nonsense. It would make more sense when when the output would be a factor ten less.
But then, motors with the same input voltage and current having a *higher* RATIO also have a *higher* output power, which little sense either. A higher reduction ratio would give an equal (same number of gear stages) or lower efficiency (more gear stages).
So, I fail to see any logic here.

> So what should I consider as the maximum current limit so as to design the protection circuit for this motor?

In the linked datasheet the MOTOR specs show the max current, so, (for what the specs are worth) I'd go for 2.5 A (max).

But I'd rather recommend using/finding a motor with *decent/plausible* specs.